# Does Facebook FB.logout() still have a dialog box?

Tags: javascript, facebook, sdk, logout

Using the new JS SDK from FB, I notice that there is no dialog telling the user they will be logged out from Facebook when logging out from my app.

What happens now is somewhat of a UI/UX problem: the user logs out from my app but ***also*** automatically logged out from Facebook without warning, which can be annoying.

Has anyone resolved this using FB SDK methods or some other function within `FB.logout();`?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to make your own UI dialog for this (or use the deprecated connect javascript sdk).  You could either pop up a UI dialog warning that they will be logged out of both your app & out of facebook, or specify a callback method in the FB.logout function which tells them afterwards that they have been logged out of both.

Comment: agreed @bkaid - considering the constraints of single logout, i don't think there's much of an option of having the user selectively logout only from my app - but i wondered if there was any implementation around for at least letting the user know they're leaving both FB and app

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately this is as designed as noted here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.logout/. As this is as designed in the Javascript SDK, I'm fairly confident in making an assumption that a server-side library will yield the same results.

Comment: thanks @demian, looks like a very basic & dry way of implementing this method - i haven't tried a 100% server side solution for FB logout with the concern of future changes on the part of FB

Answer (score 0):

I found a trick, that logs the user out of your application just client side, but leaves him logged in on facebook:

```
FB._authResponse = null;
FB._userStatus = null;
```

After that, calls to *FB.api* will return the proper error:

```
>>> FB.api('me', log)
{"error":{"message":"An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.","type":"OAuthException"}}
```

Also *FB.getLoginStatus* and *FB.getAuthResponse* are returning null or behave like the user is not logged in:

```
>>> FB.getLoginStatus(log)
{"status":null,"authResponse":null}
```

You can even log in the User again with *FB.login()*

But after a reload, the User will be logged in again automatically, if you have *status : true* in your *FB.init* config:

```
FB.init({
    appId      : 'yourappid',
    status     : false, // will not load the user automatically on pageload/refresh
    cookie     : true,  // will leave the userid in FB._userID
    oauth      : true,
    xfbml      : true
});
```

Hope that helps a bit.